# Coco-annotator server crashes unexpectedly

Tags: docker-compose, rabbitmq

I'm running [coco-annotator](https://github.com/jsbroks/coco-annotator) in a dedicated `e2-micro`  Instance on GCP, and it first it was running smoothly, but recently it has been hanging very frequently, and not only the annotation url gets inaccessible, but the whole VM! I need to manually stop and start the instance on GCP.

I checked the `docker-compose` logs and these are the last logs before the machine hanging:

```
annotator_message_q | 2022-04-19 19:09:16.735303+00:00 [erro] <0.183.0> ** Generic server aten_detector terminating
annotator_message_q | 2022-04-19 19:09:16.735303+00:00 [erro] <0.183.0> ** Last message in was poll
annotator_message_q | 2022-04-19 19:09:16.735303+00:00 [erro] <0.183.0> ** When Server state == {state,#Ref<0.2293947595.4227596289.176964>,5000,0.99,
annotator_message_q | 2022-04-19 19:09:16.735303+00:00 [erro] <0.183.0>                                #{},#{}}
annotator_message_q | 2022-04-19 19:09:16.735303+00:00 [erro] <0.183.0> ** Reason for termination ==
annotator_message_q | 2022-04-19 19:09:16.735303+00:00 [erro] <0.183.0> ** {{timeout,{gen_server,call,[aten_sink,get_failure_probabilities]}},
annotator_message_q | 2022-04-19 19:09:16.735303+00:00 [erro] <0.183.0>     [{gen_server,call,2,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,239}]},
annotator_message_q | 2022-04-19 19:09:16.735303+00:00 [erro] <0.183.0>      {aten_detector,handle_info,2,[{file,"src/aten_detector.erl"},{line,109}]},
annotator_message_q | 2022-04-19 19:09:16.735303+00:00 [erro] <0.183.0>      {gen_server,try_dispatch,4,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,695}]},
annotator_message_q | 2022-04-19 19:09:16.735303+00:00 [erro] <0.183.0>      {gen_server,handle_msg,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,771}]},
annotator_message_q | 2022-04-19 19:09:16.735303+00:00 [erro] <0.183.0>      {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,226}]}]}
annotator_message_q | 2022-04-19 19:09:16.735303+00:00 [erro] <0.183.0> 
annotator_message_q | 2022-04-19 19:09:18.480362+00:00 [erro] <0.183.0>   crasher:
```

It seems that the problem is linked to `rabbitmq`, but I have little to no knowledge about it. Can anyone point me some hints to where the problem may be?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, since this problem arose I changed to a bigger machine. It was 1GB RAM before, now it's running in a 4GB machine, and I haven't had this problem since then. [This](https://github.com/jsbroks/coco-annotator/issues/314#issuecomment-576602966) issue on github also seems to suggest that this was the problem.